# Extract objects/points inside camera view frustum

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm trying to extract objects/points (region of point cloud) inside a camera view frustum. In this case, i set up a proper camera position and rotation. And i'd like to have those partial objects which would be inside my camera view.

In other words, it's kind of like frustum culling in blender. I'll remove all points outside the camera view.

Could anyone give me some hints on doing this? Or apart of blender software, what other platform can do this work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems very hard on blender. I switched to PCL (Point cloud library) to do such kind of work.